# c# How to redirect stdout to new process window?

Tags: c#, windows

I was creating a Process using the call:

Process.Start(startInfo);

with

```
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

when the process runs with these arguments, it outputs to the new process's window fine.

However, when I make UseShellExecute false without redirecting standard output, the process no longer prints to the screen. Is this the expected behavior?

If so, how can i write to the new window that the process starts?

I can manually get the data from the process using StandardOutput.Read(), but I don't know how to write that to the new window.  When I create that window, it appears to have a console by default.

I can use pinvoke to call the C++ function on the new process:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
```

I think that I may be able to just write to the console of the new window using the function "writeconsole"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

however, i was wondering if it's possible to do this just using .net libraries. I feel like what I want isn't so complicated that this should be necessary.

All I want is to be able to start a new process and redirect the stdout of that process to the new window that is created in that process, while retaining the ability to write to stdin.

edit: 
Writing using console.writeline would just write to the main console of the program. My application is a gui app, so to be honest, I don't know exactly where it writes to, but I do know that you can see this output under the tab "output" in visual studio but not in the windows of the program itself. I think that there is a separate buffer allocated by .net for the console.

Comment: So, you have GUI application that starts console one. You were successful in reading the output and don't know how to show it in your window, right? Did you try adding a text box to your window and put text there?

Comment: this sounds like it would be possible as well, though I used a different method

Comment: Different how? In a GUI application you have to have a control where you want to put text to. `TextBox` would be an obvious choice here. What do you use?

Comment: Could you please describe you problem from the start, not the steps you try to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect `stdout` and `stdin` with [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen.htmlhttp://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen.html).

Example:

```
freopen ("file.txt","w", stdout); //or stdin
```

**EDIT:**
You could also use `createpipe()` and read from the end of the pipe. You can tell the pipe, then, where you would like your data to be read to or stored/displayed. If this is not what you are looking for, please elaborate more in depth with a comment.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to write to file.txt. I want to write to a window that was created to host the new process.  I create the process using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

this results in a new window on the screen that I wish to redirect the output of the new process to.

Comment: What if you added the following: `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`

`process.OutputDataReceived  += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data);`

`process.BeginOutputReadLine();`